# TKinter CheckButton not updating after Button.configure(state=normal)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm having trouble with tkinter check boxes updating after enabled/disable:

edit: full, running code detailing the issue. Sorry for not prepending that I had more or less psuedo code before

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, font, PhotoImage, filedialog, END, DISABLED, NORMAL
from tkinter.ttk import *


def subloop():
    for x in range(3, 25, 1):
        boxes[x].configure(state=NORMAL)


boxes = []
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")
root.resizable(False, False)
theme = ttk.Style()
theme.theme_use("winnative")

for x in range(0, 25, 1):
    boxes.append(Checkbutton(root, state=DISABLED))
    boxes[x].place(x=50, y=50 + (15 * x))

root.after(0, subloop)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Depends, if your `mainloop()` is alive while do set `="normal"`. Your example is not a [mcve].

Comment: Updating my question now: Updated, new to Tkinter, does that update show what you need for the issue?

Comment: This code won't work since `subLoop` is defined after the call to `mainloop`, and there's also a syntax error: it's `mainloop` not `mainLoop` and `Checkbutton` not `CheckButton`, and probably other mistakes. Please take the time to verify that your code is actually runnable.

Comment: Is the theme `winnative` a crucial part of the problem? If you remove that line or use a different theme, do you still have the problem? When I remove `theme.theme_use("winnative")` your code appears to work for me.

Comment: It's not crucial, just without it it does behave slightly differently (still in an erroneous manner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I remove the `theme.theme_use("winnative")` line, your code works perfectly. The code even works perfectly, just the way it should when removing that line.

One problem could be that the `winnative` theme is **not scalable**. If we replace it with a scalable theme, like this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, font, PhotoImage, filedialog, END, DISABLED, NORMAL

def subloop():
    for x in range(3, 25, 1):
        boxes[x].configure(state=NORMAL)


boxes = []
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")
root.resizable(False, False)
theme = ttk.Style()
theme.theme_use("vista")
for x in range(0, 25, 1):
    boxes.append(Checkbutton(root, state=DISABLED))
    boxes[x].place(x=50, y=50 + (15 * x))

root.after(0, subloop)
root.mainloop()
```

We replaced the `winnative` theme with the `vista` theme. The result is one that is desirable.

Hope this helps!

## Edit

We also need to remove the `from tkinter.ttk import *`. This will make the checkbuttons pure tkinter, instead of ttk.

Comment: I edited the code to that as well, but I may be seeing slightly different results. When I run the code they do in face *enable* and are no longer grayed out, but then they get auto-filled in with a box, until clicked then they alternate between a check, and blank. winnative seems to be the only one that defaults to a checkbox. Even when I set it such that (root, state=DISABLED, variable=0) then whenever I click ANY of the boxes, they all change

Comment: Hmm, I am seeing different results.

Comment: I think I got it working as intended. Removing the "from tkinter.ttk import *" line makes it such that my Checkbutton is tkinter, not tkinter.ttk. It now defaults to the correct position and updates as expected whilst keeping the 'winnative' theme overall

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my answer. Would you please upvote and accept it?

Comment: Yep, I could do that

Answer (score 1):

To anyone seeing this issue as well, removing the "from tkinter.ttk import * " made it so that the Checkbutton was from base tkinter, not tkinter.ttk

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, font, PhotoImage, filedialog, END, DISABLED, NORMAL, Checkbutton


def subloop():
    for x in range(3, 25, 1):
        boxes[x].configure(state=NORMAL)


boxes = []
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")
root.resizable(False, False)
theme = ttk.Style()
theme.theme_use("winnative")

for x in range(0, 25, 1):
    boxes.append(Checkbutton(root, state=DISABLED))
    boxes[x].place(x=50, y=50 + (15 * x))
    boxes[x].deselect()

root.after(0, subloop)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yep, might want to change the part about the winnative, since it was just the tkinter.ttk messing it up

Comment: Yes, I changed it.